# how to format number for positive value or absolute value in jstl?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

How to display positive value or absolute value of a number in jstl?

```
<fmt:formatNumber value="${-85}" format="%" /> <!-- should convert -85 to 85 -->
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use el:

```
${value < 0 ? -value:value}
```

or Create a custom EL function which delegates to [Math#abs(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#abs%28int%29).

Answer (score 0):

create you custom EL function in your code.

Comment: yes, that is what the answer to the duplicate question suggests.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `type` attribute to the expression.

```
<fmt:formatNumber type="currency" value="${-85}" />
```